# How to using randomize and then ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to first randomize and then order by a field my query.
I used this code but it doesn't order by based on "ad_type" priority and only randomize the query. 
How can I solve my problem?

```
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
            (  
                  ORDER BY a.ad_type ASC,NEWID()
            )AS RowNumber  
      ,a.Id
      ,a.ad_title
      ,b.Name a_state
      ,a.ad_brief  
      ,a.ad_pic    
    INTO #Results  
    FROM [tbl_ads] a LEFT JOIN tbl_state b ON a.ad_state=b.Id
```

Comment: Why would you want to randomize the results before sorting them?

Comment: So you want `ROW_NUMBER` but random order?

Comment: @JonathanWood ad_type is an int field between 1-3 . I want to the records with ad_type=3 come first then  the records with ad_type=2  come later with lower priority . then want to randomize the records with ad_type=3 or ad_type=2 , ... in my query.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do this `ORDER BY a.ad_type ASC,NEWID()` in the order by after the `from`?  why are we using the analytic here? otherwise you are ordering a row number randomly as selva indicated...

Comment: @xQbert I just try it for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing it this way:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber  
  a.Id, a.ad_title, b.Name a_state, a.ad_brief, a.ad_pic    
INTO #Results  
FROM [tbl_ads] a LEFT JOIN
     tbl_state b
     ON a.ad_state = b.Id
ORDER BY a.ad_type, newid();
```

Although not documented as such, a constant for the `order by` has (in my experience) resulted in no actual ordering -- just the "native" ordering of the query.

If you want to be sure, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Results
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.ad_type, newid()) AS RowNumber  
             a.Id, a.ad_title, b.Name a_state, a.ad_brief, a.ad_pic    
      FROM [tbl_ads] a LEFT JOIN
           tbl_state b
           ON a.ad_state = b.Id
     ) t
ORDER BY RowNumber;
```

Note the `ORDER BY` in the outer query.  This is the only guarantee that the result set is in a particular order.